# How to perform a dynamic creation of sections and cells to a UITableView in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, dynamic, swift3

I've got a sample code but rows per section won't show, since `numberOfRowsInSection` doesn't exist in `SWIFT 3` anymore.

I currently have the ff code:

```
let section = ["pizza", "deep dish pizza", "calzone"]

let items = [["Margarita", "BBQ Chicken", "Pepperoni"], ["sausage", "meat lovers", "veggie lovers"], ["sausage", "chicken pesto", "prawns", "mushrooms"]]

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {

    return self.section[section]

}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.section.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Result:

[image]

Can someone show the correct code for updated `swift 3`? Thanks!

Comment: You don't have it in your code sample, did you implement `numberOfRowsInSection`?

Comment: I did, but xcode highlighted it red, saying it was unknown, but adding _ before the tableView worked >.< Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your information `numberOfRowsInsection` exists in `swift3`, see below

```
 override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return section.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell?.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    return cell!
}
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Earlier I thought that `numberOfRowsInSection` was removed because xcode was highlighting it red, saying that it's unknown, nor seeing any `numberOfRowsInSection` in tableview's intellisense, but adding _ to the table view worked. Thanks!

Comment: Fine happy coding:)